# Migrating Questions

Tags: discussion

Looking at this question [How to check whether a word is abbreviated or not using Python?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13838/how-to-check-whether-a-word-is-abbreviated-or-not-using-python) and I'm not sure how it got migrated here.
Can any site just throw a question to another site?
Going through our questions here about migration, I saw something that said migrated questions are left up on other sites for 30 days. This question is no longer up on datascience.se, it was deleted on March 2. Today is June 3.

The question, imo, has nothing to do with Open Data and should be kicked to stack, or dropped by data science.

My questions are:
what is the process here?
do we have any say in questions coming to us?
how do we kick a question out?
how do we kick a question back? This should go right back to data science and they can handle it. imo.

I know I've had questions about this before, so sorry if this is similar.

I'd also like to know how to migrate questions in general. As well as how to kickback/redirect/deny a migration.

[I asked this on DS and got a great response!](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/what-is-your-process-for-migrating-questions/2459#2459)

Comment: I closed it after no response from OP

Answer (score 1):

This particular migration was puzzling because it happened 6 months after the question was asked, and even answered. Nice that you got a good reply from DS.

I think the OP is confused between acronym and abbreviation, which makes more sense for a [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) question.

---

There isn't really a process, but these are the options (as I see them):

Option 1: migrate as-is to SO as a programming question, although it will surely be closed as "unclear" there.

Option 2: request clarification from OP ([which I did](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13838/how-to-check-whether-a-word-is-abbreviated-or-not-using-python#comment18251_13838)), but in this case, OP needs to register on this site, which they haven't done yet.

Option 3: [mark as duplicate](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4812/1511), mostly depends on OP's clarification.

Option 4: close as off-topic. easy and done.

---

In this case, I'd suggest *option 4* if OP doesn't register and answer any comments something like 1 week after migrating.

Comment: maybe it would be good for english so? partially joking, but i do lurk there too and have learned some things! abbr acronyms are harder then they seem; html gave up on them.

Comment: sorry. still not really sure what i'm doing here. should have followed up sooner.